# Create and append to CSV with ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, osx-mountain-lion

So I recently had to change to OSX from Ubuntu for work and I'm having some compatibility issue with my Ruby code. I'm trying to append to a CSV and if it doesn't exist, one should be created. I've used this code in Ubuntu and it worked just fine, I have no idea what the problem is.

```
CSV.open("~/Documents/Endeca/file.csv","a") do |csv|
    csv << [Text,Date,Name,id]
end
```

When I run it now, I get an error that says "No such file or directory." I'm using ruby 2.0.0 with rvm

Comment: Do you have all directories in the path in place? I mean, does ~/Documents/Endeca/ exist?

Comment: Just try `CSV.open("file.csv", "a") ...`; does that work?

Comment: ~/Documents/Endeca/ does exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is interpreted `~` literally. If you want home directory, you should expand it using [`File.expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path).

```
File.expand_path('~/Documents/Endeca/file.csv')
# => "/home/falsetru/Documents/Endeca/file.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually just happened upon this myself, I'll have to keep that in mind in the future.